# Magento2 : admin grid action column position deviation

Tags: magento2, grid, action

[image: The action is misplaced if there are multiple columns]

When I select multiple columns, the action is in the wrong position

Answer (score 4):

> **Truncate `ui_bookmark` Table From Database**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE ui_bookmark;
```

> **Do clean cache**

Comment: Add more explenation to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to move the columns from the right side to the left of the action column.
Also, if you added those columns later, and you want them to appear properly for everyone, you can delete the records from the ui_bookmark table corresponding to your grid. You should be able to find them based on the `identifier` column.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `ui_bookmark` table
2. Filter the respective XML name `(ex:customer_listing)` in the `namespace` column.
3. Delete the records with the admin logged-in user id based on `user_id` column.

In this way, other bookmarks are kept untouched.